# My ex girlfriend haunted me with these notes

Tags: metapuzzles

After a couple of years I've decided to stop torturing myself and get help
solving her taunts from my past. Image attached. I do not know the answer (if that wasn't obvious...)

Thanks in advance your help.

> ### I’m Sorry
>
> ---
>
> $\qquad$ Let's do it again, the song im listening to right now. I'll never forget the times we had, so special, so me and you really. Haha.
>
> $\qquad$ Where do I even begin to explain all the crazy times we had. Best and most memorable times in my life forsure. I don’t doubt about that.
>
> $\qquad$ My first love, I was actually being serious about getting married.
>
> $\qquad$ My best friend I actually trusted and felt close with.
>
> $\qquad$ My boyfriend that didn’t work out as planned, lol...we tried.
>
> $\qquad$ The first time I saw you I knew you’d be in my life forever.
>
> $\qquad$ So I don’t want anything to end.
>
> $\qquad$ No MATTER how hard the circumstances are, I'm not letting you go. OR out of my life.
>
> $\qquad$ I am so sorry to hear about your mom, I really want to be there for you and your mom!
>
> $\qquad$ If theres a way I can visit her or ANYTHING please let me no. And please get well from me to her. Im praying for her.
>
> $\qquad$ I really wish things worked out for the better. Im miserable too. My dad is really stressed out about my drinking, so I hsng out with Jutin a lot cuz he doesn't care. He lets me do what I want really... and then I have my mom whos always mad and yelling at me.
>
> $\qquad$ Anyway I really love you a lot and give me a chance...
>
> $\qquad$ You know I love you, and your mother.
>
> $\qquad$ Please let me be your friend
>
> $\qquad$ Love Kristen
>
> $\qquad$ (P.S. I really miss you)

[image: note picture]

---

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please type out the words in the letter, as they're hard to read right now.

Comment: This question has been closed as off-topic because it does not seem to be related to puzzles in any way.

Comment: @Deusovi $\color{black}{\diamondsuit}$ fixed it, I think.

Comment: Thank you @user477343, I've just proof-read it and fixed a couple of things. That said, I'm afraid that Deusovi expects Bob Skaget to assert to us that this is actually a riddle, else it will remain closed.

Comment: @xhienne no problemo :)

Comment: I'd have liked to post a troll answer "Kristen Stewart"

Comment: Sorry guys my first time posting. Thanks for the help so far. Yes this is one of many examples of puzzled/coded notes/letters/images etc. I've only been left vague clues that i believe weren't aimed to actually help me. It's been over a year and I can't seem to get over not solving these so I turned here for help.

Comment: Also, it may be of importance to note that this image may be as important to the overall solution as the text itself. She refused to send me the message in plain text via email or sms. Other puzzles follow the same MO.

Comment: So since ive asserted the fact this is a puzzle can it be re opened?.